# Python - Pywin32 not opening outlook

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I have a very simple function for sending a mail with outlook.  This works fine on my own computer.  If I run the same code (via an executable made with pyinstaller) on a clients computer nothing happens.  I dont get an error message.

```
def send_email(subject, body, recipients, attachments=None):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.Body = body
    for recipient in recipients:
        mail.Recipients.Add(recipient)
    if attachments:
        for attachment in attachments:
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
    mail.Send()
    helper.logger.info("Mon(t)Fin: Mail %s is sent", subject)
```

I tried adding logging, try / except, but still nothing, the program just hangs.  After trying to execute it s not even possible to open outlook manually, outlook hangs also.

```
def send_email(subject, body, recipients, attachments=None):
    MAX_ATTEMPTS = 2
    outlook = None
    attempt = 1

    while attempt <= MAX_ATTEMPTS:
        try:
            outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
            break  # If successful, break out of the loop
        except Exception as e:
            helper.logger.error("Failed to open Outlook (attempt %d of %d): %s", attempt, MAX_ATTEMPTS, str(e))
            attempt += 1
            time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before trying again

    if not outlook:
        helper.logger.error("Failed to open Outlook after %d attempts. Exiting.", MAX_ATTEMPTS)
        return

    try:
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.Subject = subject
        mail.Body = body
        for recipient in recipients:
            mail.Recipients.Add(recipient)
        if attachments:
            for attachment in attachments:
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
        mail.Send()
        helper.logger.info("MonFin: Mail %s is sent", subject)
    except Exception as e:
        helper.logger.error("Failed to send email: %s", str(e))
    finally:
        outlook.Quit()  # Close Outlook after sending the email
```

I don't have any idea where to search or how to solve this.  All suggestions are welcome.

- I tried running the program on a different pc (my pc ok, client pc ok)
- I tried catching the error, but nothing is caught, it just hangs
- considered using a different library, that uses SMTP is not an option (limited by a whitelist of ip's)